# iFrame around video - video embed error (own hosting)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe, video-embedding

Maybe someone with more experience in WP / html can help me out here:

I want to place an absolutely positioned frame (http://fursttedesco.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/frame-empty.png) around a video I have uploaded onto our Wordpress hosting site (random example --> http://fursttedesco.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/video.mp4). I have found a code online that works, but only with the original example video, not when I try to exchange the URL using the above video.

HTML

```
<div id="laptop-panel">
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BhEWkcyXYwg?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
  #laptop-panel {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 64.5%;
        }
    
    #laptop-panel iframe {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background: url(http://fursttedesco.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/frame-empty.png) center center no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
            padding: 14.7% 12.9% 15%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

Does anybody know what could be wrong? Is it that the path for the video is wrong or maybe it doesn't work with .mp4s?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: _“I have found a code online that works, but only with the original example video ”_ – `https://www.youtube.com/embed/BhEWkcyXYwg?…` does _not_ refer to a video, it refers to a full HTML document that contains the video. Totally different pair of shoes.

Answer (score 0):

An `iframe` is a HTML element that allows an external webpage to be embedded in an HTML document. [Learn more about it here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) You cannot just give to it a video file.

Instead of an `iframe` tag, you should use [video html5 tag](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) and do something like that :

```
<div id="laptop-panel">
    <video autoplay>
        <source src="http://fursttedesco.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<style>
    #laptop-panel {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 64.5%;
    }

    #laptop-panel video {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: url(http://fursttedesco.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/frame-empty.png) center center no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        object-fit: cover;
        padding: 14.7% 12.9% 15%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Notice the new `object-fit: cover;` css rule : it's here to make your video covering the whole `video` container. You can [learn more about it here](http://learn%20more%20about%20it%20here)